# Flashed a wrong network mask in a PoE device

Tags: networking, ethernet, power-over-ethernet

I set up a network mask of `255.255.255.255` instead of `255.255.255.0` in a PoE device using the configuration software from Windows but now I cannot reach the device to fix it, due to this wrong contiguration.

I can't figure out any solution of this but factory reset, but before triying that I would rather ask if there is a better solution of this...

I've tried to set from windows network interface the netmask `255.255.255.255` and `255.255.255.0` and the same IP of camera or an IP within `255.255.255.0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is important to understand what network masks do: Combined with a host’s own IP address, they indicate which other IP addresses are *link-local*, reachable without going through router(s). This will generate an implicit route in the IP routing table.

A network mask of *255.255.255.255* (also written as */32*) means that *no* other IP addresses are link-local. It is still possible to explicitly add *routes* to indicate addresses are link-local. Links like this are sometimes called “point-to-point”.

What’s happening is the following: The device will receive your traffic, and may even act upon it. It however cannot respond, because it does not have a route to your host.

When you change the network mask on your host, the device is unaffected. It still does not have a route. Your host also won’t have one.

You can only reset the device.